# Command found only when used with `sudo` in terminal

Tags: debian, permissions, sudo

I am on debian 9. There are some commands that cannot be found when I don't type `sudo` right before. Can I disable this feature?

I have Arch Linux and it does not have this security feature. My user is in the admin group.

Comment: Please give examples of the commands. Sudo is a standard part of Linux security and has been for quite a while.

Comment: Commands that require elevated privileges work with `sudo`, of course. That doesn't mean they "cannot be found" without it. Please learn how to work in Debian and derivatives within its security model  This is explained at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo (Ubuntu is based on Debian).

Comment: I can't use iwconfig nor ifconfig without sudo, or else it will say command not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a security feature.

An executable can be run by its sole name if it's found in one of the directories specified by `PATH` environment variable. In my Debian 9 the file `/etc/profile` defines basic `PATH` like this:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH
```

This means for any user with UID `0` (in my Debian only for `root`) the default is

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

(directories are separated by `:`) and for any other user it's

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
```

I call it "default" because normally `/etc/profile` gets loaded for any user, but then the user can alter their own `PATH`. Usually `~/.profile` is a good file do do so.

When you run `sudo some_command`, `sudo` uses yet another set of directories instead of `PATH`. This set may or may not be defined somewhere in `sudo` config (`/etc/sudoers`, `/etc/sudoers.d/*`). If it's not explicitly defined, `/etc/sudoers` says the default value is

```
secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

(This is somewhat simplified, other options may alter this mechanics; see `man 5 sudoers` for details).

Note that `PATH` for `root` and `secure_path` used by `sudo` contain few directories named `sbin` (in different locations), while `PATH` for regular user doesn't. In these directories there are tools intended to be used mostly by `root`.

So if `sudo some_command` finds the executable and sole `some_command` doesn't, it's because `some_command` resides in one of directories that are in `secure_path` but not in your `PATH`.

But this is not a security feature. Any user can add all these `sbin` directories to their own `PATH`, so after typing `some_command` the shell will try to run the executable. Or they can use a full path like `/sbin/some_command`. Real security features then kick in:

- the file permissions may disallow non-root users to run it (although in Debian 9 many (all?) system executables can be run by any user);
- the file runs but it cannot get access to essential resources, so it throws an error and exits (e.g. `/sbin/hwclock`);
- the file runs and uses some authentication agent to elevate permissions without `sudo` (such a file would most likely be placed in `bin` in the first place, example: `/bin/systemd`);
- or the file runs successfully because you can run it despite it being in `sbin` (e.g. `/sbin/discover` in my Debian).

Your user account is not set up to run `some_command` without `sudo` because as a normal user you don't need it. But if you do want it anyway, just use its full path and get it (`whereis some_command` may be useful). Populating your `PATH` with all these `sbin` directories would only litter your tab completion (e.g. in Bash).

---

Tab completion deserves some explanation. Take Bash as an example shell with this functionality. The shell has `PATH` in its environment, it can read it, so if you type `another_com` and hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, it can give you a hint of `another_command` found somewhere according to your `PATH`. If `some_command` is somewhere in `sbin`, `some_com` <kbd>tab</kbd> won't find it.

Still `sudo some_com` <kbd>tab</kbd> may find it. This may seem strange because the shell cannot know `root`'s `PATH` nor it can read `/etc/sudoers` and such. What happens is the shell temporarily adds common `sbin` directories to `PATH` only to perform this search. This is done inside the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/sudo`, the relevant line is

```
local PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
```

---

To answer your explicit question

> Can I disable this feature?

Yes, you can add `sbin` directories to your `PATH`. This won't allow you to successfully run commands without `sudo` though, if they really need `sudo` (and many do).

Comment: The reason I type a command without sudo is just to make sure they exists before trying them with sudo and to save me some time. Is it common to add sbin to a sudoer user, or not recommended because it litter the tab completion. Can you explain what does 'litter your tab completion' mean ?

Comment: @wailay I don't know if it's common. By "litter" I mean your tab completion would show you things that are useless (litter, cruft) in context of normal users. Think of multi-user environment where most users don't have `sudo` access. They don't need tools from `sbin`. Few superuses or admins are exceptions, not the main population; they should know how to customize their setup. If you have your reason to expand the `PATH` then go ahead, it's your `PATH` and your convenience after all. A good practice is to do this by editing `~/.profile`, not `/etc/profile`, even if you're the only user.

Answer (score 5):

On Debian the default `$PATH` env. var for the root user (or when using `sudo`) contains the `/sbin/` and `/usr/sbin/` and `/usr/local/sbin/` directories, whereas a non-root user (even in the `sudo` group, etc) does not have these directories in the default `$PATH`.

```
user@LM193:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
user@LM193:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for user: 
root@LM193:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
root@LM193:~#
```